# How to convert psd file to cdr file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, corel-draw

I created a logo in photoshop for my website but my marketing manager want a cdr file. So I want to know is there any simple method to convert a psd file into cdr file?

Comment: Is your logo composed of vector objects? Does it contain bitmap layers?

Comment: No it is raster.

Answer (score 1):

If the file in question were composed of vectors and type, then it would be possible to do this:

- open the .psd in Adobe Illustrator, preserving type, &c.
- in Adobe Illustrator, clean up all objects, remove overlaps, set fills as needed (area fills will come in as pixel images w/in masking paths)
- save as a vector file which will import nicely into Corel

You can still do it w/ the raster image, you’ll just need to re-draw it as vectors, which arguably, all logos should exist as.

Answer (score 0):

Since your logo is in raster format you need to convert it into vector by either recreating it with shapes in photoshop or going to illustrator and playing around with the " Image Trace " presets.

[image]

After converting it into an Adobe illustrator file " .Ai "
You just need to have the latest CorelDraw for example Corel Draw X8 or Corel Draw X7 etc.

Take a look at this. Importing is easy in CorelDraw. Every vector object will remain intact and you won't even need to do changes.

[image]

Hope it helps !!! I have done it with many logos that are simple and flat.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten and save your PSD as TIFF, just in case Corel Draw may not open PSD properly (although I believe it will)
2. Open the TIFF file in Corel
3. Use Corel Draw's Trace function to convert it to vectors

Remembering from many years ago, the Trace function in Corel Draw was very good.

Answer (score 0):

As your image is raster there is no point in "Converting" it to Corel.

If for some reason he needs it inside Corel he just need to drag and drop the PSD file inside Corel.

The problem is that you made it on Photoshop in the first place. A logo should be in vectors. Yes you can aply some efects later but you should start in vectors.

Although the tracing is interesting, the best option is to trace it again inside Corel (or ilustrator and importing it in Corel).

Answer (score 0):

I suggests you should save it in Adobe illustrator format and try to import it to corel draw. Or you should save it as PSD file and import it to Corel draw then use Corel logo trace so that you will achieve a vector format of it.